# Check if row exists, Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following db structure:

```
items:
id, name, user_id

users table:
id, name

user_favorites table:
id, user_id, item_id
```

On my items permalink pages, I have an 'Add to favorites' button which inserts a new row into `user_favorites`

I want to be able to replace it for a 'Remove from favorites' button if the user already has it in their favorites.

I can't figure out the logic behind this - do I need to check if a row exists in `user_favorites` that has the current user's id and the permalink item id? This did not work for me:

```
if (Auth::user()->id) {
    if (!is_null(DB::table('user_favorites')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('item_id', '=', $item->id)->first())) {
        // remove from favorites button will show
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
$user_favorites = DB::table('user_favorites')
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('item_id', '=', $item->id)
    ->first();

if (is_null($user_favorites)) {
    // It does not exist - add to favorites button will show
} else {
    // It exists - remove from favorites button will show
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if (is_null($user)) {` actually be `if (is_null($user_favorites)) {`

Comment: Yeah was a typo, fixed :)

Comment: this is raw method. Using model is better and getting Auth::getUser()->id is faster performance wise.

Comment: When you get that info `$user_favorites`, how do you check if a specific column is null or not? For example `$user_favorites->date`

Comment: interestingly if you don't put the if and else then you get trying to get property of non object, instead of returning a null (i come from java)

Answer (score 22):

I advise you to use `exists()` or `count()` to check, not use `first()`.

The fastest way:

```
$result = DB::table('user_favorites')
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('item_id', '=', $item->id)
    ->exists();
```

Or:

```
$result = DB::table('user_favorites')
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('item_id', '=', $item->id)
    ->count();
```

SQL:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `user_favorites` where *** limit 1
```

The faster way: only select id

```
$result = DB::table('user_favorites')
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('item_id', '=', $item->id)
    ->first(['id']);
```

SQL:

```
select id from `user_favorites` where *** limit 1
```

The normal way:

```
$result = DB::table('user_favorites')
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('item_id', '=', $item->id)
    ->first();
```

SQL:

```
select * from `user_favorites` where *** limit 1
```

Comment: that `->exists()` didn't work for me but ->count() worked. (using mysql, L 5.2).

Answer (score 6):

Let `User_favorite` be a model that accesses your `user_favorites` table

```
$result = User_favorite::where('user_id',Auth::getUser()->id)
                         ->where('item_id',$item->id)
                         ->first();

if (is_null($result)) {
// Not favorited - add new
    User_favorite::create(['user_id'=>Auth::getUser()->id,'item_id'=>$item->id]);
} else {
// Already favorited - delete the existing
    $result->delete();
}
```

Comment: this one is more of eloquent approach

Comment: how to do this with multiple databases eg where I would select and use connection method how can I find if exists         $results = DB::connection("siteDB")->[ exists where id = ???? ]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do is to use [`toggle()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method of many-to-many relationship.

e.g.

```
$user->roles()->toggle([1, 2, 3]);
```

> The many-to-many relationship also provides a toggle method which
>   "toggles" the attachment status of the given IDs. If the given ID is
>   currently attached, it will be detached. Likewise, if it is currently
>   detached, it will be attached

It also returns an array which tells you if the `ID` is attached or detached in DB.