# Laravel "if else" check if exist in other table

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to use this `if else` statement like this:

```
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
<tr>
<td>    
    @if (is_null($ourcar))
           <form method="POST" action="/comments/{{ $comment->id }}/ourcars">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Our cars</button>
           </form>
        @else
         <p>saved</p>
        @endif
</td>
</tr>
    @endforeach
```

This is my controller:

```
public function browse(Request $request, CommentFilters $filters)
    {

        $lot_id     = Comment::where('lot_id')->get();
        $ourcar     = OurCar::where('lot_id', '=', $lot_id)->first();
        $comments   = Comment::filter($filters)->orderBy('lot_date', 'desc')->paginate(30)->appends($request->all());

        return view('comments.browse', compact(
            'comments',
            'ourcar'
        ));

    }
```

My database structure is:

```
comments table: id, lot_id, 
ourcars table: id, lot_id
```

My models:
Comment:

```
public function OurCar()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OurCar::class);
    }
```

OurCars:

```
public function Comment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class);

    }
```

OurCars migration:

```
Schema::create('ourcars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'MyISAM';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('lot_id')->unsigned();
```

and it same for comments

What im trying to do  is check if the lot_id already exist in "ourcars" table. If exist than return that message that this car is already saved. If not, than echo form.

With my code i have this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select * from `ourcars`
>   where `lot_id` = ? limit 1)

Can some one recommend me a better solution?

Comment: RETURN using with //

Comment: @RïshïKêsh Kümar - i need to return an array how i can do it with WITH?

Comment: return view('comments.browse',compact('comments',$comments),compact('ourcar',$ourcar) )

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar . i used this topic, but i miss understand something [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209302/check-if-row-exists-laravel)  im new in laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this message is because the `get` method will return an array , in this case it will bring all the lines of table `comment`plus it need 1 more argument at least to function.

```
$lot_id = Comment::where('lot_id')->get(); //
```

Also change your models to this

```
public function OurCar()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

And this

```
public function Comment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OurCar');

    }
```

Here an example on how can you do it based on your code.

Pass the `lot_id` on the `request`

```
 public function browse(Request $request, CommentFilters $filters)
        {
            $ourcar     = OurCar::where('lot_id',$request->lot_id)->first();
            $comments   = Comment::filter($filters)->orderBy('lot_date', 'desc')->paginate(30)->appends($request->all());

            return view('comments.browse')->with('ourcar',$ourcar)->with('comments',$comments);

     }
```

Here the view

```
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
<tr>
<td>    
    @if ($ourcar->lot_id != $comment->lot_id)
           <form method="POST" action="/comments/{{ $comment->id }}/ourcars">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Our cars</button>
           </form>
        @else
         <p>saved</p>
        @endif
</td>
</tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: maybe all my concept is wrong? as i told before i try to implement this concept in my function: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209302/check-if-row-exists-laravel)

Comment: To answer this i will need a little more info on what are you trying to do show on browse function. There will be a comment section where the people can choose cars to tag on the comments or something? The whole consept is little blurry to me.

Comment: i trying to add information form table "Comments" to table "OurCars" but before adding i want to check if this information(car) already exist in in table "OurCars"

Comment: unfortunately, something is wrong with my models: **Call to undefined relationship [lot_id] on model [App\OurCar].**

Comment: Could you add the models on your question please?

Comment: i update my question (p.s thank you very much for your time)

Comment: No problem my friend check out my answer

Comment: unfortunately the error is same, i added my migration as well

Comment: Try to add protected $table = 'ourcar'; above OurCar method

Comment: actually it was added, but not "ourcar" table, name of the table was  `protected $table = 'ourcars';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145307/discussion-between-spyrosjevan-and-dmitry-malys).